# dismissViewControllerAnimated started before present animation is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` object that is presented by segue event.
This object handles bar code scanning and initiates `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method to return to the previous View Controller.
If the bar code is scanned instantly (before segue animation is finished and `self.isBeingPresented == true`) then `dismissViewControllerAnimated` fails to run

`(Warning: Attempts to dismiss view controller <SearchBarcodeViewController: 0x155d4720> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!)`

How do I delay `dismissViewContorllerAnimated` call or cancel presentation animation before calling `dismissViewContorllerAnimated`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875538/attempt-to-dismiss-from-view-controller-while-a-presentation-or-dismiss-is-in-pr)

Comment: @Neeku, there is no answers to my question in that post. How to _delay_ dismissViewControllerAnimated or cancel _presentation animation_?

Comment: You can delay setting a timer: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html However delaying is not the solution to your problem. You must do it the right way if you want to have a proper code. There are lots of other posts discussing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should only run your bar scanning code after the view was shown just to make sure it doesn't scan the bar code before that.

So say your bar scanning code get's run on `viewDidLoad`. You should move it to `viewDidAppear`