# Dismissing an UIAlertController in an UIViewController of UINavigationController Stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a navigation controller with three view controllers. I wanted to show a loading alert in my second view controller till the resources are loaded from the server. So I added the following code in its `viewDidLoad()` method

```
alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Loading...", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And I also have a method named `loadFromURL()` which has the following code

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "server_url"))
let dataTask = self.urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            //...implementation
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })
}
dataTask.resume()
```

Everything works fine for the first time when I navigate from first view controller to the second. But when I again navigate to my second view controller from first, after returning to the first view controller, the alert controller is not dismissing and it is there forever.

Also for the second time, I get a warning like:

> Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875538/attempt-to-dismiss-from-view-controller-while-a-presentation-or-dismiss-is-in-pr

Comment: I tried that too, but the problem continues.

Comment: make the self reference week in the callback block.

Comment: Try this : `self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }`

Comment: No it is not working. Can anyone explain me the actual root cause for the problem?